# d3 line graph using csv

Tags: d3.js, filtering

I have a data in csv like this:

```
date,partner,units
2012-05-01,team1,34.12
2012-04-30,team1,45.56
2012-04-27,team2,67.89
2012-04-26,team1,78.54
2012-04-25,team2,89.23
2012-04-24,team2,99.23
2012-04-23,team2,101.34
```

I want to plot two lines (one for team1, one for team2 using this data), but I am just getting a scatterplot using the following complete d3 code, is my filtering wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

#line1 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
#line2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>
<input type="button" onclick="hideLine()">
<input type="button" onclick="showLine()">
<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the 1st line
var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.units); });

// define the 2nd line
var valueline2 = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.units); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data1.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    // format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        d.units = +d.units;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    m = d3.max(data, function(d) {
        var m = d.units;
        return m;
    });
    console.log("Max:", m);
    y.domain([0,m]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .filter(function(d) { return d.partner == 'team1'; })
            .attr("id", "line1")
            .attr("d", valueline);
    console.log("DATA", data)
    svg.selectAll(".point")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "point")
            .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
                return x(d.date);
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return y(d.units);
            })
            .attr("r", 4)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) { console.log(d.units) });

    // Add the valueline2 path.
    svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .filter(function(d) { return d.partner == 'team2'; })
            .attr("id", "line2")
            .style("stroke", "red")
            .attr("d", valueline2)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {console.log(d)});

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
function hideLine() {
    console.log("Hideline");
    d3.select("#line2").attr("style", "opacity:0");
}
function showLine() {
    console.log("ShowLine");
    d3.select("#line2").attr("style", "opacity:1");
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your filter is wrong.  You are wrapping your data in another `[]` which means the filter is only operating on the outer array.

Do this instead:

```
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data.filter(function(d) { return d.partner == 'team1'; }))
  .attr("id", "line1")
  .attr("d", valueline);
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WxWXiXHqioEEePuD0o6x?p=preview).